# Non-lattice NIST candidates affected by SVP problems

Tags: lattice-crypto, nist

I would like to know if there are non-lattice based NIST submissions that are affected by a polynomial time algorithm to Shortest Vector Problem. Are there known reduction from (e.g.) code based cryptography to SVP or any other non-lattice cryptographic system to SVP?

Comment: SVP is known to be NP-hard, so there do exist reductions from all the NIST candidates...

Comment: I guess the OP might be thinking about SVP in a regime where it is not NP hard, and where average-case hardness of LWE implies worst-case hardness of SVP? (in such a regime, as far as I know, we don't know any implications for code-based assumptions).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that concretely, the connection between SVP and LWE is essentially non-existent. In [Another Look at Tightness 2, section 6](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/360.pdf), they extract from Regev's reduction that if average-case LWE may be solved in time $T$, then worst-case $\mathsf{SIVP}_{O(n^{3/2})}$ may be solved in time $2^{500}T$. When one ignores this $2^{500}$ factor (or, theoretically, when one ignores polynomial in the dimension factors) this shows that hardness of average-case LWE implies worst-case hardness of SIVP.

Comment: but concretely it is hard to make any claim such as that. There are other concrete difficulties one can mention (generally, the quantum part of such reductions is concretely more expensive than factoring an RSA-2048 modulus, e.g. it is plausible we end up in a world where number-theoretic crypto is broken but the aformentioned reduction is not able to be run), but most angles I know of mean that there is little concrete use in the reductions, though Peikert has argued they are still theoretically useful in ensuring we haven't accidentally set LWE to be an "average-case easy" distribution